# $\mathcal{Q}:=\{C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\big|C^TC=A \}$ consists of at least $2^n$ distinct matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that for any positive-definite matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ the set $\mathcal{Q}:=\{C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\big|C^TC=A \}$ consists of at least $2^n$ distinct matrices.

The only 2 ways of constructing such matrices I know at the moment is by Cholesky decomposition or using the fact that for all symmetric matrices $A$ there is a invertible matrix $B$ such that $B^TAB=D$ where $D$ is diagonal with strictly positive entries and then constructing a matrix

$F:=
\begin{cases} 
\sqrt{D_{i,i}}  &, i=j \\[2ex]
0 &, i\ne j
\end{cases}$

Therefore $F^TF=D$ and we get $A = B^TDB=B^TF^TFB=(FB)^TFB$ and then i would just set $C:=FB$

I tried both methods with an example $3\times3$ matrix and saw that they both yielded different answers. But how do I generate $2^n$ many different matrices or show the statement without an explicit way of creating such matrices?

Comment: The statement is true when $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, otherwise it is false. E.g. when $A=I_n$ for some $n>1$, there are infinitely many orthogonal matrices $C$ such that $C^TC=I_n=A$.

Comment: @user1551 How is the statement true when $A$ has distinct eigenvalues? For example, for $A = \operatorname{diag}(1,4)$, $U\operatorname{diag}(1,4)$ is a solution for any orthogonal matrix $U$. Doesn't this yield infinitely many solutions?

Comment: @user1551 you're right. I changed the statement to "at least" $2^n$ distinct matrices This should capture the case where $A=I_n$

Comment: @BenGrossmann Ah, yes, you are right. Somehow I was thinking about $C^TAC=A$ and $C^TC=I$ although what I read was $C^TC=A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A=LL^T$ be the Cholesky decomposition. Note that $L$ has positive diagonal entries. Now let $D$ a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\pm 1$. Then $A = LDD^TL^T=(LD)(LD)^T$. There are $2^n$ such matrices $D$, generating $2^n$ different matrices $LD$. Each of these matrices $LD$ has a different pattern of positive and negative entries on the diagonal.